# Error "Snowplow: Function failed" from ping.js in console

Tags: google-tag-manager, snowplow

Ever since we implemented Google Tag Manager, we're seeing a console error on our website from ping.js: "​Snowplow: Function failed"

```html
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at Function.<anonymous> (ping.js:7:7795)
    at I (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:34:661)
    at gb.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:57:488)
    at fb.h (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:39:570)
    at u (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:56:59)
    at Function.build (ping.js:7:2535)
    at I (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:34:661)
    at gb.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:57:488)
    at fb.h (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:39:570)
    at Object.u [as build] (gtm.js?id=GTM-TL3VCNL:56:59)
error @ ping.js:7
```

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where it is or who installed it.

You can export the Google Tag Manager container.

It's a JSON file then open it with your editor and find the keyword.

You should see it is wrapped in an object where contains `tagId` or `name`.

Then you can use the `name` to check on the GTM UI. Try to pause it or asking the relevant people who knows about this.

[image]